# NoCLassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException thrown when running TomCat in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to build a server to host an slack bot on. I have included the external library org.json in the maven file and ran it and I don't get any errors in Intellij, but when I start to run it (with Tomcat Server 9.0.24) and send a POST to the server, I get both `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject`.

The solution seemed to be to include the actual .jar file in the compiling, but I think it already is as can be seen in `Project Settings -> Libraries` [image: Libraries]

The `pom.xml` includes the dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The code that triggers the error.

```
// Convert POST body to json
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jb.toString());

        // Print out the contents of challenge
        System.out.println(json.get("challenge"));
```

It's also only `org.json` that triggers the error, not the other dependency `javax.servlet`

I have seen some solutions to this, but most of them are for Eclipse or outdated Intellij. I have also tried copying the .jar files of the libraries straight to `WEB-INF/lib` but that didn't work either

Comment: Are you deploying it to tomcat as a war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the `.jar` file for the library to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and running `mvn clean`

Comment: Maven should do that automatically when building a WAR.